# how to make Quartz job start after spring boot app is up

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

```
@Component
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class UploadCronJob extends QuartzJobBean {

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        
    }
}

im getting below error is that anyother way to schedule after application start
```

Exception in thread "SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-180" java.lang.IllegalStateException: argument type mismatch

Comment: Do you use Spring? Which version of Java do you use?

Comment: @MehdiAbdolmaleki Thanks a lot for your response. Using spring boot 1.5.19.RELEASE and spring-boot-starter-quartz 2.1.5.RELEASE

Comment: @MehdiAbdolmaleki can see above code ? provide comments

Comment: You can't use @EventListener on any methods, because it needs a parameter that is the same type as event type. For example, ApplicationReadyEvent.

Comment: You should call your quartz scheduler from the method that is an event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an event like this:

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void doingSomething() {

}
```